# How to get element was created by javascript from another website

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to get data from a website: `https://liveboard.cafef.vn/`, but all data was created by javascript. So when I try `file_get_contents('https://liveboard.cafef.vn/');` and use `preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);` to analysis data in element: `<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"></tbody>`but fail.
So pls give some suggestions for this case. And my code as below

```
<?php 
    $content = file_get_contents('https://liveboard.cafef.vn/');
    
    $pattern = '#(?<=<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">).*(?=</tbody></table>)#imsu';
    
    preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches);
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: For the general solution, you'll probably need a browser emulator like Puppeteer (for Node, don't know if there's something similar for PHP)

Comment: Is there any way with jquery or some thing else like javascript ...?

Comment: Probably, but for a good, safe, general solution, better to do it on the server-side

Comment: Actually, I am not admin this website,so I don't have access to the sever, I only want to get data from it  :))

Comment: You don't need to have *their* server, you just need to have *a* server.

Comment: I am using Xampp to develop my website now. If every thing is OK, I will have a sever for this project. If I use Xampp, have any idea to resolve this problem?